# How to enable / disable a module in settings.local.php

Tags: configuration

I'm using a settings.local.php for my local development environment. This is a Drupal 7 site.

I've seen a few references to this via google search, but none of the examples are working for me. I don't want to install a module to make this work if it is possible to accomplish the same result by adding a couple lines to the settings.local.php file.

I use this file all the time for a number of sites so I know it is being read properly. I've also used it to set variables (file_temporary_path, for example) and that works too. It is just enabling / disabling modules I'm having trouble with.

Any thoughts / suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the Habitat module (https://www.drupal.org/project/habitat).

It has a UI that allows you to enter the names of modules you want turned off or on in each environment you have. Things like making sure Devel is ON in a local or DEV environment, and Views UI is OFF for a LIVE site.

It is simple to use and I haven't had any issues with it yet on the sites on which I have installed it.